# Update statement with duplicates values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table like this

Clubcard

```
AssoicaticeCard      MainCard  custID
A                       A           1
B                       B           1
C                       A           1
AA                      AA          2
BC                      BC          2
CC                      CC          2
Ar                      Ar          3
Bs                      Bs          3
Cv                      Cv          3
```

Now I need the result to be set like this where my AssoicaticeCard and MainCard have are be linked up properly.

I need the result like this to be shown. How to write an update statement for this to get achieved?

```
AssoicaticeCard      MainCard  custID
A                       A           1
B                       A           1
C                       A           1
AA                      AA          2
BC                      AA          2
CC                      AA          2
Ar                      Ar          3
Bs                      Ar          3
Cv                      Ar          3
```

I have an table with data like with which is inconsistency, now need to write an update statement to solve the issue. My table have around 1 million records.

Comment: u need update statement? or u need to display in a pattern u requested? am confused..

Comment: i have an table like data with in consitency, now need to write an update statemenyt to solve the issue. my table have around 1 million records

Comment: How can you figure out that `A` is the value you want for `1` instead of `B`? Is it because the value `A < B` or ... ?

Answer (score 2):

```
update T1
set MainCard = T2.AssoicaticeCard
from YourTable as T1
  inner join
      (
        select min(AssoicaticeCard) as AssoicaticeCard,
               custID
        from YourTable
        group by custID
      ) T2
    on T1.custID = T2.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update clubcard set Maincard = 'A' where custID = 1;
update clubcard set Maincard = 'AA' where custID = 2;
update clubcard set Maincard = 'Ar' where custID = 3;
```